# How to move UNION query results to a new table?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008

I have a sample query as shown below:

```
SELECT     *
FROM         [#temp1]
UNION
SELECT     *
FROM         [#temp2]
UNION
SELECT     *
FROM         [#temp3]
UNION
SELECT     *
FROM         [#temp4]
UNION
SELECT     *
FROM         [#temp5]
```

How do I move this request of these queries into a new table?
Note: My verison of SQL is:

```
Microsoft SQL Server 2008 (SP1) - 10.0.2531.0 (X64)   Mar 29 2009 10:11:52   Copyright (c) 1988-2008 Microsoft Corporation  Enterprise Edition (64-bit) on Windows NT 6.0 <X64> (Build 6002: Service Pack 2)
```

I tried another Stackoverflow answer I found, i.e.

```
CREATE TABLE managers AS SELECT * FROM employees WHERE desg = 'MANAGER';
```

But I get an error of : `Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'as'.`

Here was my full query that failed with the above error:

```
CREATE TABLE #temp_UNION as


SELECT     *
FROM         [#temp1]
UNION
SELECT     *
FROM         [#temp2]
UNION
SELECT     *
FROM         [#temp3]
UNION
SELECT     *
FROM         [#temp4]
UNION
SELECT     *
FROM         [#temp5]
```

Any suggestions please on how I'm goofing up?

Thank you,
Ray

Answer (score 31, accepted):

In SQL Server you have to use

```
SELECT <COLUMNS_LIST>
  INTO <NEW_TABLE_NAME>
  FROM <TABLES, WHERE ETC>
```

More information @ http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188029.aspx

Try this:

```
SELECT *
  INTO  #temp_UNION 
FROM
(
        SELECT     *
    FROM         [#temp1]
    UNION
    SELECT     *
    FROM         [#temp2]
    UNION
    SELECT     *
    FROM         [#temp3]
    UNION
    SELECT     *
    FROM         [#temp4]
    UNION
    SELECT     *
    FROM         [#temp5]
) a
```

Comment: Perfect...it worked. But what does the 'a' after the last parenthesis mean?

Comment: Its an alias for the whole UNION query and SQL Server expects an alias to be assigned to inline views.

Comment: Thanks, Cybernate. Very useful information! I know I'm not supposed to ask questions in comments, but I'm hoping you can excuse me this time. But can I query by the alias directly? Or is this purely for syntactical reasons?

Comment: What do you mean by Query by the alias directly?

Comment: The 'a' at the end of the last parenthesis. I'm going to sound like an idiot, but can I use the alias to query results from the newly created table? Instead of using "select * from #temp_UNION", can I use the alias for something? "select * from a" won't work, so what's the alias for?

Comment: The alias can be used to specify the columns.. like a.id, a.name etc.. its useful when two tables in a query have ssame column names and you want to select a specific table's column,

Comment: Ah, now I get it. Cybernate, you are the man (or woman, as the case may be)! I've accepted your answer as well. Thanks again!

Answer (score 3):

```
insert into temp_UNION
select * from (
SELECT     *
FROM         [#temp1]
UNION
SELECT     *
FROM         [#temp2]
UNION
SELECT     *
FROM         [#temp3]
UNION
SELECT     *
FROM         [#temp4]
UNION
SELECT     *
FROM         [#temp5]
)
```

Answer (score 1):

or you dont need to use derived table. You can do this too

```
SELECT *   INTO  #temp_UNION  
FROM         [#temp1]     
UNION     
SELECT     *     FROM         [#temp2]     
UNION     SELECT     *     FROM         [#temp3]     
UNION     SELECT     *     FROM         [#temp4]     
UNION     SELECT     *     FROM         [#temp5]
```